# Restart Docker Container when Gunicorn Breaks

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

Consider a simple `docker-compose.yml` that looks something like this:

```
version: "3"
services:

  api:
      image: my-container:latest
      command: ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "wsgi:app"]
      volumes:
          - ./api:/api
```

The `api` service is a `nginx`-based Python Flask web app that runs `gunicorn`. Occasionally, I will break the Flask app and `gunicorn` will throw a non-zero exit code and stop running. I then rebuild all my containers. I have tried the following to restart the container upon fail to no avail:

```
version: "3"
services:

  api:
      image: my-container:latest
      command: ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "wsgi:app"]
      volumes:
          - ./api:/api
      deploy:
          restart_policy:
              condition: on-failure
              delay: 5s
              max_attempts: 5
              window: 60s
```

This configuration ignores the `deploy` config option with the following warning: `WARNING: Some services (api) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use`docker stack deploy`to deploy to a swarm.` I'm not deploying to a swarm.

How can I automatically restart my container upon failing with a non-zero exit code?

Answer (score 0):

The `deploy` section only takes effect when deploying to a swarm with `docker stack deploy`, and is ignored by `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose run`.

The `restart` section only takes effect when using `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose run`.

```
version: "3"
services:

  api:
      image: my-container:latest
      command: ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "wsgi:app"]
      volumes:
          - ./api:/api
      restart: no|always|on-failure|unless-stopped
```

See docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart